# jQuery: ColReorder set to default order

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have my DataTables initialised as below

```
var table = $('#today').DataTable( {
    "ajax": '/getMainData/24102019/json',
    "ordering": false,
    enableFiltering: true,
    filterPlaceholder: 'Search for something...',
    "scrollY": 300,
    "scrollX": true,
    "pageLength": 500,
    "lengthMenu": [[100, 1000, -1], [100, 1000, "All"]],
    processing: true,
    'language':{ 
        "loadingRecords": "Loading ...",
        "processing": "Loading ..."
    },
    "columnDefs": [
        {
            "targets": [ 2,14 ],
            "visible": false,
            "searchable": true
        },
        { "width": "200px", "targets": [3,16,17] },
        { "width": "300px", "targets": [15] }
    ],
    colReorder: true,
    "initComplete":  function (settings, json) {
        afterTableInitialization(settings,json);
    }
    });

// RE-ORDER COLUMNS     
        function afterTableInitialization(settings, json) {
            console.log('[+] Column reordering');
            table.colReorder.order( [ 0,1,22,23,24,25,2,3,4,5,6,13,7,8,9,10,11,12,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,26 ] );
            $('#loading').modal('hide');
        }
```

So far, so good, everything works

However I have a select menu which triggers a new ajax search as below

```
$('select#days').on('change', function() {
    $('select.multiselect').multiselect('deselectAll', false);
    table.ajax.url( '/getMainData/'+this.value+'/json' ).load();
    table.search( '' ).columns().search( '' ).draw();
});
```

Obviously at this point, the columns are the wrong way around.

However if I set the columns back to the original ordering, well, this doesn't actually happen/work and the data gets all out of sync with the columns. The original ordering never seems to change

Any advice?

```
// GET NEW DATA BASED ON DROPDOWN VALUE
        $('select#days').on('change', function() {
            table.colReorder.reset();
            $('select.multiselect').multiselect('deselectAll', false);
            table.ajax.url( 'getMainData/'+this.value+'/json' ).load();
            table.search( '' ).columns().search( '' ).draw();
            table.colReorder.order( [ 0,1,22,23,24,25,2,3,4,5,6,13,7,8,9,10,11,12,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,26 ] );
        });
```

I try the reset option and the column headers revert back to what they were initially. However the colReorder seems to be triggered before the Ajax completed so it's out of sync again

Answer (score 1):

You've tried using [colReorder.reset()](https://datatables.net/reference/api/colReorder.reset())?

```
$('select#days').on('change', function() {
    $('select.multiselect').multiselect('deselectAll', false);
    table.colReorder.reset();
    table.ajax.url( '/getMainData/'+this.value+'/json' ).load();
    table.search( '' ).columns().search( '' ).draw();
});
```

**EDIT**

```
columnDefs: [
    {
      render: function(data, type, row) {
        return '<div>' + data + '</div>';
      },
      targets: 0
    },
    ...
]
```

Comment: Thanks - the reset works but when I try and reorder afterwards, nothing happens

Comment: Wondering why you're having this issue at all, I have a site running using live data with datatables and custom reordering but I've never had this mixup.  Maybe because I have supplied a `render` function to each cell to select the data explicitly?  Have you tried that?

Comment: 26 columns and 15k rows - I'm guessing it might be overload? Can you point me to an example please?

Comment: Well you'd only need it for the columns, I'd done it with over 30 and no issues, let me update my answer with an example

Comment: Actually, I think you need to add an id to the `div` created it render, then update that manually.  Not the best solution but it does work if you can't figure out something else

Comment: Thanks - the reset works a treat but it looks to me like the reordering is happening before the data is loaded